# syncdb and updating database schema in Django

Tags: database, django, django-models

I have been working on developing the models for a Django app. I am working on it in my spare time. I have an issue when it comes to testing. Whenever I realize I have a mistake in my models, I have to go through the trivial but annoying process of dropping the corresponding database and then recreating it and running `python manage.py syncdb`. Apparently, this is because Django's `syncdb` cannot change the database schema. I do not fully understand what that means. Although, I know it is a pain to have to keep deleting and recreating my database every time I try and change something in my models.

Is there a better way of doing this? Is something wrong with my install? I feel like this is such a simple thing to fix that I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing is wrong with your installation. It is a limitation of django.

There is a 3rd party app called [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/), which can be used for managing "migrations" (changes to database models). It is a very widely used app for managing database changes.

There are lots of documentation online to help you understand how south works, and how to use it.

[This is a good tutorial on south](http://www.djangopro.com/2011/01/django-database-migration-tool-south-explained/)

Comment: wow, thats sort of surprising. Oh well, guess I just gotta do it right the first time

Comment: Well. Requirements always change. This is definitely a handy tool to use